# Equation of a vertical plane given $2$ points

Tags: plane-curves

A vertical plane passes through points $(1, -1, 1)$ and $(2, 1, 1)$.

With three points on a normal plane, I just found two vectors and found the normal by cross-product of the vectors, but I'm not sure what to do here.

Help, please.

Comment: If the plane is "vertica", then $c=0$ in the equation $ax+by+cz=d$. If you want the normal form of the equation, then additionally $a^2+b^2=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways you can represent a plane mathematically. One of the most succinct ones is using the normal and a position vector as

$$\hat{n}\cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{c})=0$$

Where $\hat{n}$ is the vector normal to the plane and $\vec{c}$ is any vector *in* the plane.

Now in your case you have two points and you know that the plane is vertical, which I'm assuming it means that is perpendicular to the $x-y$ plane. With that information you can find a third point contained in the plane for example by setting the $z$ coordinate of any of the given vectors to 0.

Now with 3 vectors $v_1=(1,-1,1);\; v_2=(2,1,1);\; v_3=(1,-1,0)$ you can calculate the normal vector using the cross product of any two vector lying in the plane, for example $v_1-v_2$ and $v_2-v_3$.
This gives you that
$$\hat{n}=(v_1-v_2)\times (v_2-v_3) = (-2,1,0)$$
Which makes sense as you know that the $z$ coordinate must be 0 in order to be a vertical plane.

With that information you can now write your plane equation as

$$(-2,1,0)\cdot (\vec{x}-(1,-1,1))=0$$

Or if you expand it with $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)$ you can get

$$2x-y-3=0$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be -3?

$$-2(x-1)+(y+1)=

-2x+2+y+1=

-2x+y+3=

2x-y-3=0$$

?

Comment: Yes, I just edited it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since the plane is vertical, it is parallel to the vector $(0, 0, 1)$.